# Talend studio tWaitForFile issue

Tags: file-transfer, talend

I am using a tWaitForFile component from a Talend Studio Project and I want to know if there is a way to be sure a file to trig the event when this file is fully written on disk.

I tried to set the advanced property : "Wait the file to be released" 
but it seems this is useless, the file trigs the component even it is not finished to be transmitted.

Does anybody have the same behaviour and a solution to fix that?

The version of Tos is: 4.2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advanced setting "Wait for file to be released" only works on Windows.  It has no effect on Unix, which probably explains why it did not work for you.

It is generally difficult, or even impossible, for a Unix process to figure out if a file has been written completely or not.  Consequently, there is no easy way to do this in Talend, either.

(For example, if you wanted to wait until the file size does not change anymore -- how long do you wait?)

A common solution involves the process *writing* to the file: Create the file under a different name first, and when it is written completely, rename it to the name that the other process expects.  That way, it will show up in its full size immediately.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware that feature was only available on Windows. Finally I did something similar to your solution as a workaround: I transfer the big zip file and then when it is finished, I transfer a control file which just contains the name of the zip. The other Talend job with tWaitForFile, waits for the control file and no more on the zip file.